# Magento 1.9.3.1: Default (incorrect) price showing for configurable products in cart after customer group change

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, shopping-cart

I'm sitting with the problem described in the title.

Our site has different customer groups, but for the sake of simplicity I'm only going to use 2 example groups - Wholesale and Retail.

To replicate the issue I do the following:

1. I start off with my customer belonging to the Retail group
2. I login to frontend and add some items to cart and then logout
3. I then change my customer group to Wholesale which has different prices
4. When I login on the frontend again my items are still in the cart, so I checkout, but then configurable product items are now using the default price instead of the price for the new customer group that's been assigned to the customer.

Simple products are fine though.

Clicking the "Update Shopping Cart" button on the cart fixes the issue, but this isn't really a solution.

Is this a magento bug? Is there a fix?

Answer (score 0):

when products have been added to a cart, their data is copied into a quote.
this is normal and is done to ensure transaction consistency.

The question is what action triggers customers group to change? If this is something that happens in frontend, then cart have to be made aware of that by

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$cart->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();
```

Comment: The update of the group will only ever happen in the backend.
So I guess a solution may be to create observer listening for update of the customer and then triggering collectTotals() if the customer has an existing quote? Or is doing this in the frontend the better option?

I am curious though, is this a magento bug?

Comment: and because of this totals for pending cart sessions are not being reassembled

Comment: I would not consider this a bug. Merchants are not meant to change customer group individually in admin and expect pending carts to reload :)

Comment: Alright, I'm with you. Thank you.

But changing a users group is something that will happen from time to time and there unfortunately is no way to avoid this. So my question is - what do you think is the best way to resolve this?

Comment: I would suggest to observe on some general controller dispatch event, in method body check if it is the cart controller and force recollect totals. This will somehow impact general performance of this page.

Comment: Alright. I don't think there's any way around this so I'll give that a try. Thanks